# Windows Powershell Command to show PHP process

Tags: powershell

I'm new in PHP. I'm following PHP with MySQL Beyond the basics Lynda tutorial. They used another command line environment on mac OS. But I'm using Windows powershell. They run the command  `ps aux grep httpd` on those environment. Which is not for windows powershell.
What is the alternate windows power shell command for `ps aux grep httpd`?

Comment: A tip: a lot of powershell cmdlets have aliases representing their linux counterparts.  For example, typing `Get-Help ps` pulls up the built in help page for `Get-Process`. You can use this to discover powershell cmdlets for many familiar utilities.

Comment: You can also use the `alias` command to find equivalent powershell commands.  For example, if you type `alias ps`, it returns the definition `Get-Process`.  If you type `alias` with no argument, it returns all definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `get-process` cmdlet

```
get-process httpd
```

You can also use wildcards.  For example, if you want all the process names that begin with h:

```
get-process h*
```

Comment: Thanks! But I need complete alternate windows powershell reference